# Cannot uncompress a segmented zip file

Tags: compression, zip

I've run the following command: `zip -r -s 200M myzip folder` to compress the folder into multiple zip files (200M each).

I now have a small myzip.zip (7mb) file and the files:

```
myzip.z01
myzip.z02
myzip.z03
...
```

and so on.

The issue is that I cannot unzip the content. I'm running unzip unix archive.zip but I get "bad zipfile offset (lseek)". Furthermore, I need to extract them in Windows environment as well, and there I only have Windows 7 extractor I guess.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your previous questions, you're using OS X with Zip 3.0 and UnZip 5.52. If I zip some files with

```
zip -s 5m -r test test/
```

I get several files, including one with the `.zip` extension. Running

```
unzip test.zip
```

works just fine and deflates all the contents.

Zip has the problem that some files can not be read on other systems, that's why I would suggest trying different programs like @Sandeep suggested.

#### Fixing archive

You can also try to fix the original:

```
zip -F archive.zip --out archive-fixed
zip -FF archive.zip --out archive-fixed
```

#### Alternatives

I don't know if you really need to use Zip, but I think you might be better off using Tar and GZip.

```
tar cvf archive.tar.gz directory
split --line-bytes=600m archive.tar.gz part
```

and then again concatenate the files, either using `cat` on Unix-like systems or `copy` on Windows.

```
cat part* > archive.tar.gz
copy /b part1+part2 archive.tar.gz
```

Extract the file on Unix systems by double clicking. 7Zip on Windows is a good tool for that purpose.

Comment: So what compression format you suggest. Yeah exactly I'm compressing on mac and uncompressing on Windows.

Comment: @Patrick I added Tar+GZip as an alternative. You might want to give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can try

- [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)
- [Winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm)
- [Peazip](http://www.peazip.org/)
- [Universal Extactor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract)

All work well with extraction, some work and some don't with what you're trying to achieve just trial and error.

Comment: I'm now using 7Zip and I get "unsupported compression method" error. I will try Winrar, but do you think it is the extraction software, or rather a bad compression ?

Comment: It is most likely bad compression, but some software can handle corrupted files, such as Winrar, it has the possibility to fix corrupt archives.